# $R/Soc(R_R)$ and a semisimple $R$-module

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I am searching for a ring $R$ and a semisimple $R$-module $M$ such that for any $r\in R$, either $r-r^2\in Soc(R_R)-ann_R^l(M)$ or $r+r^2\in Soc(R_R)-ann_R^l(M)$. Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: May I ask what's the motivation for your searching?

Comment: @Xam I am zooming in the triangular matrix rings $[R, M, 0, S]$. Also, I have in mind the well-known fact that  idempotents of the quotient $R/Soc(R_R)$ lift modulo $Soc(R_R)$.